# control calling mode activity in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast, callblocking

i want to make an android app that when device receive a call,my app could reject,answer or minimize call mode and do somethings else in device menu while device is ringing.

for this,i should get handle of default answer app of android.

i know that we can access activities from another applications,like maps

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

how could i do this?

Comment: What all have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast on receiving a call and then create IDL interface for getting core Telephony service. Please refer to [this](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/333253/Block-Incoming-calls-in-android-without-single-rin) tutorials.

Comment: i try this and report soon,thanx